# can't build min3d project

Tags: android

i'm using linuxmint 11 with eclipse indigo and adt .... 
i tried to build the sample project in the min3d framework but did succeed .
i tried importing the project , change the src to min3d in .project , and choose the right android platform .

but when i choose to build the project , i get eclipse does build the min3d_src directory :
"The declared package "min3d" does not match the expected package"
see image if you didn't understand .

http://www.hostpic.org/images/99Screenshot.png

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will sort this automatically for you :

[image]

Comment: i don't have the change package declaration , instead i have remove package declaration ?!?!?!?

Comment: You don't have it because it is in the default package, rename your package by 'Rt click > Refactor > Rename`

Comment: i'm not sure i understand you ,

Comment: and why the interface shown as a folder and not like the others as packages (see picture)